# Property '_id' does not exist on type. Getting type error when trying to access property _id on result of a promise in nestjs application

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, nestjs, mongoose-schema

In my nest application I am getting type error when calling `_id` on `user` because mongoose defines the `_id` automatically & therefore its not present in my schema which is defined as type for the promise.

When the promise type is changed to any like `Promise<any>` then there is no type error.

```
async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    const createdUser = await new this.userModel(createUserDto).save();
    return createdUser;
  }
```

but I want to know is this the correct way or I should be doing something else.
I do not want to define `_id` in schema to solve this issue.

```
 @Prop({ auto: true})
 _id!: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
```

**user.schema.ts**

```
// all the imports here....

export type UserDocument = User & Document;

@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class User {

  @Prop({ required: true, unique: true, lowercase: true })
  email: string;

  @Prop()
  password: string;

}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

**users.controller.ts**

```
@Controller('users')
@TransformUserResponse(UserResponseDto)
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Post()
  async create(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
      const user = await this.usersService.create(createUserDto);
      return user._id;
  }

}
```

**users.service.ts**

```
// all the imports here....  
   
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<UserDocument>) {}

  async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    const createdUser = await new this.userModel(createUserDto).save();
    return createdUser;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use [`Document.prototype.id`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-id) to get the `_id` in string form. In other words use `user.id` instead.

Comment: It's okay to define the _id in the schema, if the problem is to define the same property to all your schema you could define a base model and extend that model to your models.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger `user.id` is also showing type error like I said because in the User schema `id` is not present.

Comment: A typescript error? If you return `UserDocument` in your `UserService` you should have access to the id. The `User` type does not have an id property.

Comment: Hello i am  also facing this problem . did you solved it and how ?? is it possible without manually define _id property?

Comment: @MahmudulHassan I removed the promise type from User to Any and the type error went away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `create` service method should return `Promise<UserDocument>` instead of `Promise<User>`. `UserDocument` has the `_id` property specified.

```js
async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<UserDocument> {
    const createdUser = await new this.userModel(createUserDto).save();
    return createdUser;
  }
```

Comment: This kind of information should be in the NestJS doc. Thank you !